# How to get a previous element to another using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I want to do this.

```
<p class="validator">This is an error!</p>
<input type="text" validator="isGoodValue" value=""/>

<p class="validator">This is an error 2!</p>
<label>
<input type="text" validator="isGoodValue" value=""/></label>

<div><p class="validator">This is an error 3!</p></div>
<label>
<input type="text" validator="isGoodValue" value=""/></label>    

<script>
$('input').change( function() {
 if (!isGoogValue( $(this).val() )) {
     $(this).GET_ME_THE_VALIDATOR_ABOVE_ME().show();
 }
 else {
     $(this).GET_ME_THE_VALIDATOR_ABOVE_ME().hide();
 }
});
</script>
```

What may be the code of GET_ME_THE_VALIDATOR_ABOVE_ME to get the exactly

validator above, independent of HTML structure? or What function of jQuery do this work...???

I'm trying to use closest, parent, prev.. but that doesn't works well.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 if (!isGoogValue( $(this).val() )) {
     $(this).prevAll('.validator:first').show();
 }
 else {
     $(this).prevAll('.validator:first').hide();
 }
```

Comment: I don't think `toggle` is appropriate here. If the `.validate` is visible at the start, it will hide it, but if you change the input again (to another valid value) it will reappear!

Comment: Still doesn't quite work. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NqNvY/). The problem is that the way the OP has structured it, the `.validator` is a sibling in for the first input, but for the other two you have to go to a descendent of the parent's sibling. I'm not sure if you can do that with a simple selector.

Comment: That doesn't works, only works for the first input, as you can see the HTML has 3 inputs with their independent errors (p).

Comment: You can take away the labels on some inputs since they dont seem to do anything and do it like this http://jsfiddle.net/FL7cJ/1/ if you need the html markup like you have right now i can change the jquery code

Comment: @Anton: A simple `.prev` works just as well. There's no need for `.prevAll` or `:first`. But I agree with you that the question is a bit contrived. The real solution is to have some consistent structure to you HTML such that the path through the DOM from your input to the error message is the same.

Answer (score 1):

The real solution is to have some consistent structure so that you error messages aren't completely disconnected from your inputs and then you can use a solution similar to what Anton suggests.

Alternatively, if it's absolutely impossible to restructure your HTML to something sane, you could give IDs to all your inputs and IDs to your error messages that can be related somehow. For example, input 1 has an ID of `input1`, and it's corresponding error is `input1error`. Then you can do something like this:

```
$('input').change( function() {
     if (!isGoodValue( $(this).val() )) {
         var id = $(this).attr("id");
         $("#" + id + "error").show();
     }
     else {
         var id = $(this).attr("id");
         $("#" + id + "error").hide();
     }
 });
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NqNvY/1/).

Now it doesn't matter where your errors appear, so long as they can be related via their ids somehow.

Another solution show in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NqNvY/3/) assumes that the nth input corresponds to the nth validator like this:

```
$('input').each(function(index, elem) {
    var idx = index;
    $(elem).change(function() {
        var val = $('.validator').eq(idx);
        if (!isGoodValue( $(this).val() )) {
            val.show();                
        }
        else {
            val.hide();
        }
    });            
});
```

Comment: this is well, but think about this: jQuery ---> write less, do more!. In jQuery some things are easy like $(this).closest('thing').show() ... in the case of this, <p validator><input><p validator><input> has an order, obviusly validator first is for the first input, second validator is for the second input, etc independent of HTML structure... There are implicit IDs .... I think the solution is create a function: 1. Get the HTML above the INPUT 2. Get the first element (.validator) in reverse order of that HTML.

Comment: @CrisHongKongCRISHK: Sure, but jQuery doesn't read minds. It can only work with the structure that is there. Another way to do it would be to find all the inputs, figure out the index of the input that has changed in that collection (call it n), then find the corresponding nth `.validator`.